# Trouble recalling image from file system of server

Tags: php, filesystems

So I've finally got my images to be stored in folders on my server when a user uploads a photo. What I need to figure out now, is how to users can upload that photo (to the file system folder), then have that photo automatically be shown on index.php page, within the content wrapper. Any help is great.

The image I want displayed would be inside the image div, which is inside the photo div,and is above the imageInfo div, which contains a description of the image.

Here's the code for my index.php page (it already has a sample image there for reference):

```
<div id="contentWrapper">

   <?php echo "<div id='photo'><div id='image'><img src='https://i.imgur.com/1QJFnJz.jpg'><div id='imageInfo'></div></div></div>";?>

    </div>
```

Here is the code for my image upload form:

```
<body>
<div id="contentWrapper">
    <img style="margin-left:150px ; margin-top:70px" src="http://i.imgur.com/YjvuqaP.jpg" height="100">
    <div id="postForm">
        <form action="posts_check.php" method="POST" name="posts_form" id="posts_form" onSubmit="return validateFrom()" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="image" id="image"><br>
        <textarea name="description" id="description" placeholder="Enter a description of your work here...";></textarea><br>
        <input type="submit" name="upload" id="upload" value="Upload">
        </form>
    </div>
    <h2 style="font-family:Arial ; color:#9b6bb4">Before you upload your file:</h2>
    <ul style="font-family:Arial">
        <li>Your file must be smaller than 1MB, so if you need to compress your photo, visit <a style="text-decoration:none ; color:#9176FF" href="http://jpeg-optimizer.com/">JPEG-Optimizer</a></li><br>
        <li>Make sure that your file is 'at least' <em><strong>480px</strong></em> wide. (If not, the image will look weird when uploaded)</li><br>
        <li>Make sure that you are the owner of the work that you are uploading. (Copyright suits suck)</li><br>
        <li>Make sure you include a detailed description of the work to give others an idea of how you did it.</li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

Here is the code to send the uploaded image to a folder on the server:

```
<?php

session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['username']))   {
    header('location: must_login.php');
}

    $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","") or die ("No SQLI");
                mysqli_select_db($conn, "sample") or die ("No DB");


if (isset($_FILES['image']) && ($_FILES['image']['size'] < 2097152) && (in_array($_FILES['image']['type'], array('image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'image/jpg', 'image/gif')))) {

$chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";

$rand_dir_name = substr(str_shuffle($chars), 0, 15);

mkdir("photos/$rand_dir_name");

if (file_exists("photos/$rand_dir_name/".$_FILES["image"]["name"]))
{
echo $_FILES["image"]["name"]." Already exists";
}
else
{
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"],"photos/$rand_dir_name/".$_FILES["image"]["name"]);

//echo "Uploaded and stored in: phoyoss/$rand_dir_name/".@$_FILES["image"]["name"];

$username = 'ralston3';
$description = $_POST['description'];
$image_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
$image_id_before_md5 = "$rand_dir_name/$image_name";
$image_id = md5($image_id_before_md5);
$date = date('Y-m-d');

$sqli = "INSERT INTO `photos` (username, description, image_name, image_id, post_date) VALUES ('ralston3','$description','$image_name','$image_id','$date')";

mysqli_query($conn, $sqli) or die ("No query");

header('location:index.php');


//$profile_pic_name = @$_FILES["profilepic"]["name"];
//$img_id_before_md5 = "$rand_dir_name/$profile_pic_name";
//$img_id = md5($img_id_before_md5);
//$profile_pic_query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO photos VALUES ('','test','$user','$date','$description','http://localhost/tutorials/findFriends/userdata/user_photos/$rand_dir_name/$profile_pic_name','no','$img_id')");
//header("Location: upload_photo.php");

         }  

    } else { 

        header('location:error.php'); 

    }

?>
```

Comment: Select the row(s) with image(s) in question, fetch and echo using a loop. Then something like `<img src='".$row['image']."'>` bay-sick-ah-lee. Google `"fetch image from database"` you'll end up with many results.

Comment: So say I wanted to fetch the row with the latest image that user has uploaded. Would I retrieve the row with the highest image id? Assuming i give each image a unique id auto_incremented?

Comment: Assuming you have a date/time column, which I believe you do, you would order by/group by date ASC to show the most current image and using a WHERE clause for a particular user in question.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$sql=mysql_query("select id, username, description, image_name, image_id, post_date from photos ORDER BY id DESC");

echo "<div id='contentWrapper'>";
while($image=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
echo "<div id='photo'><div id='image'><img src='https://yoursite.com/photos/$image[$image_id]/$image[$image_name]'><div id='imageInfo'></div></div></div>";
}
echo "</div>";
?>
```

note you must add id identifier as image id (create new id field with INT) image_id you mentioned abou is handling folder name, so it must contain random value so cannot be used to ORDER method